# regular expression allow point and Latin letters

Tags: c#, regex

I have regular expression allow only point and Latin letters. But this expression miss string where exist space. In my code I need see true and false. But I see true and true. How it fixed?

```
String str1="asdfgsadgs";
String str2 = "asd fgsx cgvbn adgs";
bool res = Regex.Match(str1, @"[a-zA-Z]|.").Success;
bool res2 = Regex.Match(str2, @"[a-zA-Z]|.").Success;
Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.WriteLine(res2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this regex

```
 ^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that `.` in a regular expression, in general, means "any character". Thus `[a-zA-Z]|.` means "a letter, or any character", and will match a space.

You either need to

- *escape* the `.`, by putting a `\` in front of it, giving `@"[a-zA-Z]|\."`, or
- move it inside the character class, where it no longer needs to be escaped, giving `@"[a-zA-Z.]"`

Your second issue, as Benoit points out, is that your regular expression is asking "does *any* character matching this class exist anywhere in the input", where you really want to ask "does *every* character in the input match the class". I won't duplicate his answer here.